# magento geolocation redirect

Tags: magento, plugins, geolocation

Do you know any plugin that redirects only users to certain store based on the IP (geolocation)?

I have found theese two:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-and-currency-auto-switcher.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2t-geoloc-va-automatic-store-and-currency-switch.html

but the problem is that they change also the currency and not only the store.

As an alternative does anyone know a simple coding method to do that? (I should mention that I do not have any knowledge of geolocation so I did not try any coding at all yet)

Thank you,
Mugur

Comment: What if you don't have the currency enabled?  If you only have one currency then it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I think either one of these extensions would be easy enough to edit to exclude the switch to currency.  Just locate the code in the module that makes the currency switch and comment it out.

Comment: @seanbreeden I have several currencies set with different VAT values and they are quite complicated. I do not wish to change that however.

Comment: In either one of those extensions it may be possible to modify them to not switch currencies and to only switch stores.  I think it would just be a matter of installing one of the extensions and commenting out the code that does the currency switch.

Comment: I installed it and apparently it did not affect the currecy probably due to the fact that the VAT modifications are made in the core. So it is fine. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Whoever modified your site should never touch the Core.  At the very least ask them to move their core mods to /app/code/local/.

Comment: I know that. However the client requested that and he accepted that he is not going to make any upgrade. It is risky ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your index.php and see how it loads a website/store.

It is relatively simple to install a geoip module on both Apache and Nginx, this module will then enable you to have a $_SERVER value for country code. You can then place a simple php switch/case block in your index.php that sets the website/store values used to call Mage.php and have whatever logic in there to suit your setup.

I don't believe the module route (even if one exists) is what you need given how straightforward it is to write the switch/case for your country->store mappings. You will also need to put in there some extra option for testing purposes, e.g. if the IP address requesting the page is your PC then show whatever store it is you need to test.

Answer (score -1):

Anyway, you can always chose one of [Magento's free extensions](http://www.mageworx.com/magento-extensions-free.html).
`Geo Lock` or `Geo IP Locations` are free and restricted versions of the first extension you linked.